# How to prevent the "flash" on Kindle e-readers?

Tags: kindle, ebook-readers

I have avoided buying a Kindle e-reader and opted instead to read on my laptop to avoid the "flash" that occurs on the Kindle screen. The background and font will invert colors briefly every 5-10 pages or so and it's a bit distracting. I'm aware the flash is to prevent burn-in, but is there anyway to override this function?

Comment: The flash should happen with each page turn. This is because how the refresh/redraw happens with E Ink screens. It's different than LCD screens. If you'd like, I can show a video of mine to see if behaves the same as you're explaining. Or just look up Kindle paper whites on YouTube.